# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:390

Tags: magento2.3.0, php-7.2, dom

DOM package already install.

also follows:
**sudo apt-get update**
then install php7.2-dom

Comment: please attempt installing\enabling the php-xml extension.

Comment: @magefms,Its already enable ,also check php info file.

Comment: have you check this? https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/quot-Fatal-error-Uncaught-Error-Class-DOMDocument-not-found-in/m-p/99540#M5779

Comment: have you restarted your apache server ?

Comment: also check php -v and make sure you installed `dom` extension for current php version.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?